# Solving modified Fibonacci Nuggets [Project Euler 140]

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations, project-euler

I am trying to solve [Modified Fibonacci golden nuggets](https://projecteuler.net/problem=140).

The generating function could be written as:
$$A_G(x)=\frac{x(3x+1)}{1-x-x^2}$$

Let it be some $y\in\mathbb N$, then
$$x(3x+1)=y(1-x-x^2)\\
x^2(3+y)+x(1+y)-y=0\\
x=\frac{-(1+y)+\sqrt{(1+y)^2-4(-y)(3+y)}}{2(3+y)}$$
So for $x\in\mathbb Q$, for some $k\in\mathbb N$
$$k^2=5y^2+14y+1\\
5k^2=25y^2+70y+5=(5y+7)^2-44\\
X^2-5Y^2=44\text{ where }X=5y+7,\; Y=k$$
So I need to solve the diophantine equation $x^2-5y^2=44$.
I note that $(7, 1)$ is a solution. Then $x^2-5y^2=1$ has a solution $(9, 4)$. And we know that other solutions will be given by 
$$x+y\sqrt5=\pm(7+\sqrt5)(9+4\sqrt5)^n$$
This gives me the list:
$$\color{red}{(7,1)},(83,37),(767,665),(6923,9053),...$$
But this was not sufficient and I came to know we need to find other fundamental solutions which form their own classes like the one above for $(7, 1)$

Can someone illustrate how to find other solutions/fundamental solutions. Also any help regarding the problem would be great.

Comment: What do they mean for "the first 30"? The first 30 greater than zero or the 30 which give the first 30 rational x?

Comment: former one. The values of A greater than zero sorted and the first 30 of them

Answer (score 1):

Give a look at this: https://pastebin.com/Ne5x7Vm5

I manage to spend some time looking at the golden nuggets and found a pattern by structure them by propety.

I realised the nuggets had a x2 or x4 to the next nugget. But it still there was a gab. I realised this gab had a pattern. I after realised the gab had two hidden variables x and y.
x has been used on all even nth nugget. And y has been used on all uneven nth nugget.

n^k is the nth nugget

n^k = (n^k-1 * 2) - x

n^k = (n^k-1 * 4) - y

After each 2 nuggets that where generated the x and y needed a update.

x = (y - x) / 2

y = 14 + 19x - 2y

For me its still a mistory where the x and y comes from and where it has relations with. If someone has a clue please give a comment.

Comment: I did some more research and here some result. I expected to get a pattern between the sequences but i havent seen a universal algorithem yet. I hope to find something later if i do some more patterns.

Sequence: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ... : [link](https://pastebin.com/HrBQYxft)

Sequence: 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, ...: [link](https://pastebin.com/grwDs8Em)

Sequence: 1, 4, 5, 9, 14, 23: [link](https://pastebin.com/4jvptunb)

Sequence: 1, 5, 6, 11, 17, 28: [link](https://pastebin.com/Q5BGJenE)

Comment: Update: I did some more research on different Fibinacci sequences and found a better algo to generate the golden nuggets. [link](https://pastebin.com/qd6xPfEi)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
The sum is 5,673,835,352,990

The first 30 Golden nuggets are

$2, 5, 21, 42, 152, 296, 1050, 2037, 7205, 13970, 49392, 95760, 
338546, 656357, 2320437, 4498746, 15904520, 30834872, 109011210, 
211345365, 747173957, 1448582690, 5121206496, 9928733472, 
35101271522, 68052551621, 240587694165, 466439127882, 1649012587640, 
3197021343560$

I noted that x converged to $-\phi$ and $-\phi+1$ so I used several approximations of the continued fractions $-1;1;1;1;\ldots$ for $-\phi$ and $-0;1;1;1\ldots$ for the second.

Then I plugged those values in the generating function and got the 30 integers.

Comment: I am the 3127th to post the correct solution :)

Comment: My question was how to solve the Pell's equation mainly :)